# How do I have Calibre automatically create a cover image from a non-ebook file?

Tags: pdf, calibre, image, cover

I am an RPG publisher and use Calibre to maintain my research library (PDF, mostly) and my stock art library (various image files).

When I load a PDF, Calibre automatically creates a cover image using the first page of the PDF.

When I load image files, it cannot. I must assign the cover image explicitly. Is there a way to have Calibre automatically create a cover image from a 'book' that is a raster image (JPG or PNG format)?

Comment: A raster image is not a book and can't be expected to have the same features and usage. JPG and PNG files are not recognized as books by Calibre because, well, they are not books. When loading a book, the program tries to extract the cover from a set of recognized formats, if you give it something else (a picture, an audio file, a movie.. you name it) this won't work. I suggest you to use a dedicated program to manage images, something like XnView, Digikam and the likes. Calibre is meant to manage ebooks, if you use it for something else you must accept to have a limited experience.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid this isn't the answer you need, and it's been a long time coming. Although I don't recall the method, be it via an add-on or whatever, I succeeded in using a jpg image of my own design (CS6) as a cover. It was available in the Calibre cover customization window, so applying title/author text in the usual way was no problem. So, yes, there's an easy to use method, and if I re-discover it before you do, I'll post the details.